# Como copiar vários arquivos de uma pasta para outra usando Fs.copy

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de saber como faço para **copiar** mais de um arquivo para um outro local (pasta). Utilizando o `fs.Copyfilesync`. No exemplo eu só consigo copiar somente um arquivo:

Exemplo:

```
fs.copyFileSync('C:/xmlpath/file.xml', 'C:/test/file.xml');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const copyFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.copyFile);

function copyFiles(srcDir, destDir, files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(f => {
       return copyFilePromise(path.join(srcDir, f), path.join(destDir, f));
    }));
}

// Uso
copyFiles('src', 'build', ['unk.txt', 'blah.txt']).then(() => {
   console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Com `const copyFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.copyFile);` a função é transformada numa Promise para facilitar a utilização, na função `copyFiles` é recebido  a pasta de origem (srcDir), a pasta de destino (destDir) e a listagem de arquivos (files), depois retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) com o [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) dando um `map` em `files`

Dessa forma ela vai fazer o processo de cópia de forma paralela, não sendo necessário esperar cada cópia terminar para executar a próxima

Retirei o código [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54818489/5325043) resposta